# In the FullCalendar dayClick event, can I get the events that already exist in clicked date?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

In the FullCalendar dayClick event, can I get the events that already exist in clicked date?

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/mouse/dayClick/

Let me explain a little about my project 
I'm writing a simple php site that allow user to add/edit event on calendar.

- Only single event can add to a date.
- If user click on empty date, New event popup will show (I use dayclick event).
- If user click date with existing event, Edit event popup will show (I use eventclick event).

The problem is when user click outside of event area (upper area or bottom area) of a date with existing event, it raise dayclick instead of eventclick.
How can I trigger eventclick event and skip dayclick event if there is existing event in the date?

Answer (score 19):

Are your events stored on the client side or on the server side?  If on the client side, this should work specifically if you want the event in that clicked time:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents', function(event) {
                if(event.start <= date && event.end >= date) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            });
    }
});
```

This will give events that overlap the clicked time and are stored on the client side.  For the all-day slot, it will give all events overlapping that day.

If you want all events on that date itself, regardless of whether the allDay slot or a time slot was clicked.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
            if(!allDay) {
                // strip time information
                date = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDay());
            }
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents', function(event) {
                if(event.start <= date && event.end >= date) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            });
    }
});
```

If your events are stored on the server, you'll want to take the date provided in your dayClick callback and use it to construct a call to your server to get the info in whatever format you need.

**EDIT** If doing a round trip or trying to get the information other ways

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
            var startDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDay(), 0, 0, 0).getTime();
            var endDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDay(), 23, 59, 59).getTime();
            var cache = new Date().getTime();
            $.getJSON("/json-events.php?start="+startDate+"&end="+endDate+"&_="+cache,
                function(data) {
                    // do stuff with the JSOn data
                }
    }
});
```

And if you don't want the round trip, you can also take a look at what happens in, say, refetchEvents in fullCalendar.js.  If you don't mind diverging from the fullCalendar trunk, you can save off fetched events somewhere so that you aren't doing a bunch of DOM manipulation (depending on the number of events, as they get large that will get unwieldy).

Comment: Thanks for your reply 

my events are come from serverside by using
events: "json-events.php"

So do I need ajax call to retrieve events?

Is it possible to write a javascript function that accept date as parameter and return event list of given date without going back to server side?
Because I can see the events for date on client browser.  Isn't it possible to query events from calendar dom?

Comment: If you are trying to do work via the DOM, looking at the code in the fullcalendar.js file will help you out signficantly.  You'll notice that Adam Shaw, the creator, counts tds to know what date to place various events on.  So yes, it's definitely possible to do this.  It's just going to be a lot more painful and require a lot of DOM manipulation - perhaps enough that a round-trip to the server would be just as fast.  Also, DOM manipulation won't get you the JSON of the events, but the divs that are placed inside to describe the events, showing only the displayed info.  May be enough, may not.

Comment: I can see the td that represent each date in calendar dom.
But events are stored as separate divs after calendar table.
I don't see this event divs and td relation.  
So where can I get the relation between event div and date td?

Thanks

Comment: For what view?  Month?  AgendaDay?  AgendaWeek?  BasicWeek?  BasicDay?  For week and day, the headers have each date, that is true.  But then in the same column (for week and day) are the events, in tds.  For month view they are associated.  At least, this is true in 1.4.3 and 1.4.4.

Comment: I'm using Month View.  Could you tell me more detail how date and events are associated?

Comment: Try looking in the _renderSegs code (or renderSegs before 1.4.4).  It shows you how the structure of the divs are built up.

Comment: Regarding code snippet #1: Be careful with "all day"-events which seem to have `event.end` set to `null`. Because of this event.end >= date will evaluate to false. The following works for me: `return (event.start <= date && ( (event.end == null && event.start.getDate() == date.getDate()) || event.end >= date));`

Comment: Also `if(...){ return true }else{return false}` is somewhat redundant, not? You could directly return the boolean value as I don't believe it will become more `true|false`, will it? :>

Answer (score 7):

I've just come across this issue myself whilst finding a solution for entering public holidays on to a calendar. I found this to be a good solution for full day events. I hope this can help someone else further down the line.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({                
    eventClick: function (event) {
        ShowEditScreen(event.id);
    },
    dayClick: function (date) {
        var events = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents');
        for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
            if (moment(date).isSame(moment(events[i].start))) {
                ShowEditScreen(events[i].id);
                break;
            }
            else if (i == events.length - 1) {
                ShowCreateNew(date);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Comparing date with ```moment``` is what worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Moment library. For example:

```
$('#endDate').val(moment(endDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss'));
```

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

Answer (score 0):

Exested answers didn't work for me so there is working code:

```
dayClick: function (date, jsEvent, view) {
    var count = 0;

    date = date.toDate();
    var startDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate(), 0, 0, 0);
    var endDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate(), 23, 59, 59);

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents', function (event) {
            if (event.start.toDate() >= startDate && event.start.toDate() <= endDate
                || event.end.toDate() >= startDate && event.end.toDate() <= endDate) {
                        count++;
                    }
                });
    //count - number of events on this day
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is is you need all your events for the current day in another function:

```
            var date = $('.js-calendar').fullCalendar('getDate');
            date = date.toDate();
            var startDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate(), 0, 0, 0);
            var endDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate(), 23, 59, 59);
            var todaysEvents = $('.js-calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents', function(event) {
                if (event.start.toDate() >= startDate && event.start.toDate() <= endDate
                    || event.end.toDate() >= startDate && event.end.toDate() <= endDate) {
                    return true
                }
            });
```