# FullCalendar display events on dayClick

Tags: php, fullcalendar

The `dayClick` in fullCalendar is defined as:

```
dayClick: function (start, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
    alert('You clicked me!');
}
```

This is triggered when the user clicks on a day.

I wanted to access data of events when a user clicks on a particular day. Sort of merging the eventClick function in dayClick so that when I click on a particular day, I get the event title, starttime, endtime of all events occurring that particular day.

Comment: What if the day doesn't contain any event?

Comment: @RahilWazir: In that case, I guess it would give a `null`. I mean, suppose if we are storing the events in an array, then that array would be null.

Comment: Then why don't you use [eventClick](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/mouse/eventClick/)

Comment: @RahilWazir: I tried it. But wasn't able to figure out how to combine eventClick with dayClick. I'm pretty new to javascript. I wanted all events data for the day when clicked on a particular day.

Comment: @xan is there an event on that day ?

Answer (score 1):

I hope this help  you

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
                var startDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDay(), 0, 0, 0).getTime();
                var endDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDay(), 23, 59, 59).getTime();
                var cache = new Date().getTime();
                $.getJSON("/json-events.php?start="+startDate+"&end="+endDate+"&_="+cache,
                    function(data) {
                        // do stuff with the JSOn data
                    }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I don't know how this will help. I already have a calendar with certain events. I just want to show the title of events when I click a day (title of all events that occur on that day). Also, your code doesn't work.

Comment: Why not? I think is the same question asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2516050/in-the-fullcalendar-dayclick-event-can-i-get-the-events-that-already-exist-in-c

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
eventClick: function(xEvent, jsEvent, view) {
    alert("Title: " + xEvent.title             //Get the event title
          + "\n StartTime: " + xEvent.start    //Get the event start date
          + "\n EndTime: " + xEvent.end        //Get the event end date
    );

    console.log(xEvent); //See your console for all event properties/objects
}
```

[`xEvent`](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/) properties/object lists.

Comment: This is triggered when a user clicks on an "event". I want the event data when a user clicks on "day".

Comment: @con_28 If there's no event on a day then of course it make no sense there would be event data. You can get event data only when there is event registered to the day.

Comment: In my case, all days have atleast one event except Sunday.

Comment: Then the above snippet will work for you except Sunday!

Comment: The above code works if I click on an event. I dont want that at all. I want a mechanism to display a particular day's events on clicking a day. If the day doesn't have any event, it will simply output a null object.

Comment: @con_28 Can you be more specific? What do you mean by "clicking a day"? Do you want to bind the event to day container/text or what?

Comment: Please read my question. I've mentioned it that I want a mechanism where if a user clicks on a "day" (dayClick), I get the events occurring on that day.

Comment: @con_28 The `dayClick` has no parameter to get event data. Why do you want `dayClick` mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

```
dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
    var startDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDay(), 0, 0, 0).getTime();
    var endDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDay(), 23, 59, 59).getTime();
    var cache = new Date().getTime();
    $.getJSON("/json-events.php?start="+startDate+"&end="+endDate+"&_="+cache,
        function(data) {
            // do stuff with the JSOn data
    });
    alert('ENTROU!');
},
```

now it works

it opens a alert, you just have to put the information wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
  var date2 = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate()+1);
  //This gives the next day of the clicked day('date' contains the clicked day)

  var todaysEvents = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents', function(event) {
    // Below statement returns the EVENT OBJECT of the clicked day after comparing the two dates
    return event.start >= date && event.start < date2;
  });
  // You can now access the returned object & extract what you want
  // console.log(todaysEvents); --> returns the complete object
  // console.log(todaysEvents[0].title); --> returns that day's event title
},
```

I Hope this helped.

Comment: You first have to convert the date from moment js to javascript date using toDate function. So jsDate = date.toDate(), and use jsDate instead of date

Comment: date.getDate()+1 will not work... this could be 32.  invalid date.